# WinUI3 propagate pointerpressed event to the background controls

Tags: events, winui-3, event-propagation

I have grid and this grid has few children which are placed one above another like stack (not stackpanel). Topmost control has semi transparent background. And when user clicks on the topmost control I need this event to be cought by the control behind. Is it possible, because in WPF there are few types of events and it is possible.

Here is Scheme of controls. Black is parent grid. green is the control behind the red control which is topmost.
Nothing happens when I set args.Handled = true or false to the routedeventargs of PointerPressed event of Red control

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set at least `Transparent` as the `Background` for the other `Grid`s.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?